# How to Alter primary Key value dynamically whlie joining tables in mysql query

Tags: mysql, join

I am working on mysql joining process

I have two table for chat__user and chat_message.

chat_user:

```
   id    name  socketid

   1     raj    123
   2     kumar   1234
```

chat_message:

```
  id   chat_from  chat_to  message

   1      123     1235       hello
   2      1235    123        how can i help you? 
   3      123     1235       HOw track my order?
```

Then, John this two tables Using  "**chat_message.chat_from = chat_user.socketid OR chat_message.chat_to = chat_user.socketid**"

Myquery:

```
    SELECT * FROM `chat_message` INNER JOIN `chat_user` ON chat_message.chat_from = chat_user.socketid OR chat_message.chat_to = chat_user.socketid
```

Result:

```
chat_from  chat_to  message                    id   name  socketid 

123        1235     hello                      1    raj    123 
1235        123        how can i help you?     1    raj    123 
123        1235     HOw track my order?        1    raj    123
```

I need to change **id** field value to auto increment.

for Example:

```
chat_from  chat_to  message                 id   name  socketid 

  123        1235    hello                   1    raj    123 
  1235       123     how can i help you?     2    raj    123 
  123        1235    How track my order?     3    raj    123
```

Suggest me How to alter the field?..

Comment: sorry to edit my question, This is I need .  Thanks.

Comment: so you perform joins based on ephemeral socket ids. That could make for interesting viewing of other people's chat sessions. Check out `alter table` and it may require a data transformation based on what you have now.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be wanting to just add a sequence number, which can be done using a variable:-

```
SELECT sub1.chat_from,
        sub1.chat_to,
        sub1.message,
        @id:=@id + 1 AS id,
        sub1.name,
        sub1.socketid  
FROM
(
    SELECT chat_message.chat_from,
            chat_message.chat_to,
            chat_message.message,
            chat_user.name,
            chat_user.socketid  
    FROM chat_message
    INNER JOIN chat_user 
    ON chat_message.chat_from = chat_user.socketid 
    OR chat_message.chat_to = chat_user.socketid
) sub1
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT @id:=0
) sub0
```

However normally you would want to add an ORDER BY clause in the sub query to try and force the order that the sequence number is in.

Also not sure if you want the sequence to reset between each chat conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below Query

```
SELECT @cust_id := @cust_id+1,c.* 
FROM `chat_message` c,(select @cust_id :=0) r 
INNER JOIN `chat_user` ON c.chat_from = chat_user.socketid 
OR c.chat_to = chat_user.socketid
```